# foreach keyword in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I know the meaning of `foreach` in programming and when to use it. Is there a `foreach` keyword in Java? I tried to find a list of keywords but there is only `for` and not `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach is not a java keyword (IDE recognizes it and puts the "[For-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)" loop).

Answer (score 26):

To my knowledge, Java does not have a `foreach` keyword (unlike C# if I am not mistaken). You can however, iterate over all the elements in an `Iterable` collection using a modified version of the for loop:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
...
for (String str : list)
{
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) link for more information.

Comment: Additional info: Eclipse defines a _foreach_ code template, which will give you this kind of for-loop when you use it...

Answer (score 8):

As of Java 1.8, Java now has a foreach loop ...

```
package org.galarik.arick;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExampleForEach {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("Mom");
        strings.add("Dad");
        strings.add("Dad's Java");
        strings.add("Mom's Java");

        // Original for loop
        int stringsSize = strings.size();
        Object[] oldStrings = strings.toArray();
        for(int stringIndex = 0; stringIndex < stringsSize; ++stringIndex ) {
            System.out.println("Original Content: " + oldStrings[stringIndex]);
        }

        // For loop, as of Jova 1.5
        for (String string : strings) {
            System.out.println("All Content: " + string);
        }

        // forEach loop as of Java 1.8
        strings.stream().forEach((string) -> {
            System.out.println("For Content: " + string);
        });

        // Using forEach loop to do a filter
        strings.parallelStream().filter(someString -> someString.contains("Java"))
                .forEach((someOtherString) -> {
                    System.out.println("Content With Java: " + someOtherString);
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No.  To do a "foreach", you write `for( Type variable : collection ){ .... }`

(Yes, I know it doesn't have to be a `Collection`, just an `Iterable` or an array - I'm just trying to write clearly)

Answer (score 3):

No, There is no keyword like `foreach`.
And just wanted to add that enhanced for loop was added just for coding convenience.
Compiler puts it back to old java format.
Like:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String str : list)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Will be converted to:

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    String str;
    for(Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); System.out.println(str))
    {
        str = (String)iterator.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

NO. `foreach` is not a keyword in Java.

The `foreach` loop is a simple syntax for iterating through arrays or collections—implementing the  `java.lang.Iterable` interface.

In Java language, the `for` keyword and the `:` operator are used to create a `foreach` loop.

```
// Java example
String[] oddBalls = {"one", "three", "five", "seven"};

for (String currentBall : oddBalls)
{
   System.out.println (currentBall + " is an odd number.");
}
```

The basic `for` loop was extended in Java 5 to make iteration over arrays and other collections more convenient. This newer `for` statement is called the `enhanced for` or `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have `foreach` keyword like `C#`.If we use `foreach`in java it shows errors.
If we want to use `foreach`, have to implement like below.

```
//sample Java Code
List<WebElement> radioButtons = driver.findElements(By.name("color"));

for(WebElement  radioButton : radioButtons)
    {
        if(radioButton.isSelected())
        {
            System.out.println(radioButton.getAttribute("value"));      
        }
    }
```

> Here we have list of Web Element-Radio Button and we are checking each
> element for particular condition.We are using `for` keyword and `:`
> operator here in `Java`.
>
> In case of `C#` we can implement same scenario like below

```
//C# code Sample
foreach(WebElement radioButton in  radioButtons)
{
  //implementation comes here 
}
```